# How to safely and reversibly escape string quotes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

What is the Ruby equivalent of [Python string's `encode('string_escape')` and `decode` functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)?

In Python, I can do the following:

```
>>> s="this isn't a \"very\" good example!"
>>> print s
this isn't a "very" good example!
>>> s
'this isn\'t a "very" good example!'
>>> e=s.encode('string_escape')
>>> print e
this isn\'t a "very" good example!
>>> e
'this isn\\\'t a "very" good example!'
>>> d=e.decode('string_escape')
>>> print d
this isn't a "very" good example!
>>> d
'this isn\'t a "very" good example!'
```

How to do the equivalent in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `inspect`

```
irb(main):001:0> s="this isn't a \"very\" good example!"
=> "this isn't a \"very\" good example!"
irb(main):002:0> puts s
this isn't a "very" good example!
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts s.inspect
"this isn't a \"very\" good example!"
```

note that decoding is much trickier, as inspect also escapes anything not valid in utf-8 files (like binary), so if you know that you will never have anything aside from a limited subset, use gsub, however, the only real way to turn it back into a string is parsing it, either from your own parser or `eval`:

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "\" hello\xff I have\n\r\t\v lots of escapes!'"
=> "\" hello\xFF I have\n\r\t\v lots of escapes!'"
irb(main):002:0> puts s
" hello� I have

         lots of escapes!'
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts s.inspect
"\" hello\xFF I have\n\r\t\v lots of escapes!'"
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> puts eval(s.inspect)
" hello� I have

         lots of escapes!'
=> nil
```

obviously, if you are not the one doing the `inspect`, then don't use eval, write your own/find a parser, however its perfectly safe if you are the one calling `inspect` right before `eval` and s is guaranteed to be a string (`s.is_a? String`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks like that's what I need for encoding, what about the decoding though?

Comment: `string.gsub(/\\"/, '"')` perhaps? It's so trivial there really isn't any built-in methods.

Comment: well, eval is really the only way to get back, as it escapes non-printing binary also

Comment: @byteit101, that sounds a bit dangerous, similar to using JavaScript's `eval()` to get back JSON-encoded data? I am also not expecting non-printable binary, but pretty much anything else.

Comment: Maybe you or @tadman could incorporate `eval` and/or the `gsub` solution into a complete answer *including decoding* for me to accept?

Comment: `eval` is absolutely **not** the thing you want here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this:

```
'string"and"something'.gsub '"', '\"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant but if I wanted to avoid dealing with escaping I just use `%q[ ]` syntax

```
s = %q[this isn't a "very" good example!]
puts s
p s
```

Will give

```
'this isn't \ a "very" good example!'
"'this isn't \\ a \"very\" good example!'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for my use case, I need to deal with user-supplied strings so that is not an option.