# Does Ruby guarantee that eval(str.inspect) == str?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, eval

I recently found myself needing to generate a simple Ruby script based on user input, some of which needs to be included in the script as a string literal.  While in my specific case this input comes from a trusted source, I would still like to do this in a way that will not break even if the input string happens to contain e.g. quotes, backslashes, newlines, hash marks or other unexpected metacharacters.

The obvious solution (as recommended in the accepted answer to [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990844/how-to-safely-and-reversibly-escape-string-quotes-in-ruby)) would be to use the [`String#inspect`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:inspect) method, whose documentation says that it:

> Returns a printable version of *str*, surrounded by quote marks, with special characters escaped.

The documentation, however, stops just short of explicitly stating that evaluating the output of `String#inspect` as Ruby code will return the original string.  And, in fact, I did technically manage to come up with a counterexample using non-Unicode strings:

```rb
pry(main)> str = 0x80.chr; eval(str.inspect) == str
=> false
```

However, all the strings I need to encode are Unicode strings, so this counterexample is of only theoretical interest to me.  But I'd still like some documented guarantee, hence the following questions:

1. Is `eval(str.inspect)` guaranteed to be equal to `str`, if `str` is a Unicode string?
2. If not, is there some other method of escaping a string literal in generated Ruby code that *is* guaranteed to always work?

Also, a bonus question:

3. Is `eval("'" + str.gsub(/[\\']/, { "\\" => "\\\\", "'" => "\\'" }) + "'")` always guaranteed to equal `str`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to summarize the results of my investigation so far (including [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503402/max)'s now-deleted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75866728) that introduced me to `String#dump`):

---

The documentation for [`String#inspect`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:inspect) does not guarantee that `eval`ing its output yields the original string.  However, at least as of Ruby 3.0.2, the documentation for [`String#dump`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:dump) *does* make that guarantee:

> This method can be used for round-trip: if the resulting `new_str` is eval'ed, it will produce the original string.

Thus, it appears that the answers to my questions #1 and #2 are:

1. No, `eval(str.inspect)` is not guaranteed to equal `str` by the Ruby documentation (although in practice it does seem to work; see below).
2. OTOH, `eval(str.dump)` *is* documented to always equal `str`.

---

Of course, while documentation is nice to have, it's also a good idea to make sure that the actual behavior matches what's documented.

Based on my testing, it seems that *empirically*, at least on relatively modern Ruby versions, both `String#inspect` and `String#dump` *seem* produce output that, when `eval`ed, equals the original (Unicode) string.

Specifically, using the following test string (which I believe contains all currently assigned non-surrogate Unicode characters, as well as a few extra potentially problematic character pairs and sequences),

```rb
unicode_points = (0..0xD7FF).to_a + (0xE000..0xE007F).to_a
str = unicode_points.map { |i| i.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) }.join("")
str += "\#{foo} \\\\ \\\' \\\" \r\n\t"
```

it seems that both `eval(str.inspect) == str` and `eval(str.dump) == str` evaluate to true on both CRuby 2.6.10 and 3.3.0dev and JRuby 9.3.10.0 (which are what I happen to have installed and conveniently available).

---

The `gsub` method in my bonus question #3, however, does not *quite* work; the problematic character sequence is `"\r\n"` (i.e. ASCII CR+LF), which apparently gets collapsed into a single LF even inside single quoted strings.  Specifically, it turns out that `eval("'\r\n'") == "\n"`(!).

(I discovered this based on a warning saying `warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space` that I got when testing with the string containing all Unicode characters.  This led me to suspect that there might be some funny parsing going on with newlines, so I added `"\r\n"` to my test string and got a mismatch.)

---

Also, while testing `String#dump`, I happened to notice that the test string above fails to round-trip properly with `String#undump`.  A simpler test case demonstrating the same issue is e.g. `str = "\u0001\uABCD"`, for which `str.dump.undump` raises `RuntimeError: hex escape and Unicode escape are mixed`.

Apparently the problem is that `String#dump` encodes characters in the ASCII [C0 control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) as hex escape codes of the form `\xNN`, but non-ASCII Unicode characters above U+007F in the form `\uNNNN` (or `\u{NNNNN}` for characters outside the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)), which `String#undump` for some reason does not like.  While this is *not* a problem with `eval()`, which seems to happily accept the output of `String#dump`, it probably still counts as a bug.  I have now reported it as https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/19558.